# Next Auth doesn't work with custom basePath

Tags: next.js, next-auth

My NextAuth are returning 404 when searching for `api/auth/session` at credential provider custom login, seems like Next Auth are pointing to the wrong url.

My next.config.js have a basePath that points to a subfolder `basePath: '/twenty-test'` and my `NEXTAUTH_URL` is already set to my subdomain,
but when I go to my credential provider login custom page (that was working at localhost because it was not at a subdomain), i see an 404 error at console like `https://explample.com/api/auth/session 404`.

This is my custom provider config:

```
 providers: [
    CredentialProvider({
        name: 'Credentials',
        type: 'credentials',
        async authorize(credentials) {
            // 
            if(credentials.email == "john@gmail.com" && credentials.password == "test"){
                return {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'John Doe',
                    email: 'john@gmail.com',
                    permition: {
                        group: 2,
                        level: 0
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

    })
],
```

This is my next.config.js

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  basePath: '/twenty-test',
  images: {
    domains: ['example.com'],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This is my `NEXTAUTH_URL` env variable

```
NEXTAUTH_URL="https://example.com/twenty-test/api/auth"
```

This is my `getCsrfToken` config

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
return {
    props: {
        csrfToken: await getCsrfToken(context)
    }
}
}
```

My project are not on vercel. I'm using a custom server config to deploy with cPanel

Comment: Are you sure the `NEXTAUTH_URL` environment variable is being injected and picked up correctly when your app is deployed? Are you able to log the expected value for `NEXTAUTH_URL` in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on building the app in localhost and deploying on server.

The app was building expecting NEXTAUTH_URL as localhost, and simply changing the .env variable on server didnt worked.

The solution was building the app on server.

Another workaround was replacing the localhost NEXTAUTH_URL ocurrences after building with the value of NEXTAUTH_URL on server.